# picture element don't respect viewport meta tag

Tags: css, media-queries

picture element don't respect viewport meta tag.
Any one know how can I solve this?

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>dpi</title>

    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>

    <style type='text/css'>
        body { padding: 50px }

        div.dpi {
            background-image: url(dpi.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 32px 32px;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            display: inline-block
        }

        @media (min-width: 361px) {
            div.dpi {
                background-image: url(dpi_sm.png);
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='dpi'></div>

    <br>

    <picture>
        <source media='(min-width: 361px)' srcset='dpi_sm.png'>
        <img src='dpi.png' alt='' width='32' height='32'>
    </picture>
</body>
```

when it runs in a standard desktop with a 1366px resolution, the picture element loads dpi_sm.png as expected.

however, when it runs in a android device, it keeps loading the dpi_sm.png image.

I tested, and it only loads the dpi.png image when I set the media to "(min-width: 981px)". It should consider the meta tag viewport, shouldn't it? But the zoom is being the default 980px, even when the viewport meta tag is there

The div and css media query works fine in both cases. Just the picture element is being a problem.

Comment: Try adding `width=device-width` to your `content` property.

Comment: I could be wrong but part of what the picture element does is relegate some responsibility to the browser to determine which image to display, [<picture>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture). The browser may be choosing dpi_sm.png because it feels that is the appropriate option.

Comment: Hi TylerH, I already did this, but without success.

Comment: Hi hungerstar, the behavior you are pointing out happens when you use the img tag with the "sizes" and "srcset" attributes. When you use picture element, acording to specs you are dictating what image the browser should use. As an example, when I set min-width:981px in the media attribute, it works as expected. Clearly, the picture tag is not respecting the viewport meta tag, and it is considering the standard zoom for mobile phones (980px)

Comment: When trying this out with Chrome's device emulation mode, I see that the right images are being displayed for a Nexus 5 (360x640). Which Android are you testing this on? Which Chrome version? If you still see an issue can you please open a bug on https://crbug.com ?

Comment: I'm testing it in the Firefox Mobile on Android 5.0 on Samsung Galaxy S5. In the device itself not in the emulation. Do you think this it is a bug?

Comment: Could well be. File a bug here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi